# Append image to div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just need to append `img` to `div`. This is code:

```
 .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {                                                                

                            var li = $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item);
                            li.append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>");

                            var divClass = item.label + "-class";
                            li.append("<div class = '"+divClass+"' >" +  +"</div>");  
                            for(var i = 0; i<item.productpictureurl.length; i++){                                    
                                $("." + divClass).append("<img width='100px' height='100px' src='" + item.productpictureurl[i] + "' />");
                            }




                            li.appendTo(ul);
                            return li;
```

I can find `div` in my page. Pictures `url` is ok too. And What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is variable **li**

Comment: You need to add more code

Comment: With li all is ok. This div has appended to li successfully